# dsymutil and static libraries - "Unable to open object file"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, dsym

I'm importing a 3rd-Party static library into my iOS Applicaton (using Xcode 5.1.1). When building the project I receive hundreds of warnings of the following type:

```
warning: (i386) /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Development/SDKNAME/AWSS3.framework/AWSS3(S3ListObjectsResult.o) unable to open object file
```

These warnings are caused by **dsymutil** when it tries to generate a DSYM file. For some reason dsymutil is trying to find the object files for code contained in the framework at the local path of the developer that built the framework.

Which build settings in the static library would cause such an issue?

I found a couple of responses on Stack Overflow and other platforms: [What do these Dsymutil Warnings mean in XCode 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489692/what-do-these-dsymutil-warnings-mean-in-xcode-4-5) but none of them really explains the underlying problem.

I'm fairly new to Mach-O/DSYM things, so let me know if you need any other information to understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the answers in the post you linked to stated, this is a problem with your library that you have no control over.  Your linker sees objects in the library that can't be opened.  I'm having the same problem with a different framework and am waiting on the vender to send me an updated version compiled with a more recent build of llvm.  I suggest you do the same and contact the author of the library.

EDIT 8/26:
Just got confirmation from the author of the library.  These warnings occur because of incorrect symbol stripping settings for release builds in a project.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same Dsymutil warnings. I get rid of these warnings by changing the 'Debug Information Format' in the build setting

In your xcode project > Build Setting > Under Build Option > Change Debug Information Format to **'DWARF'**.

I am not sure that it actually hides the warnings or completely get rid off.

Comment: it get rids of but also get rids of information needed when it comes to symbolication crash reports...